# Added a clickable popup with bootstrap but every popup is the same

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looping through a database on an index page to show all the pictures someone has uploaded. From there I thought it would be cook if you could click any you liked and it'll popup bigger to give you a closer look. I found the code in bootstrap to do so. Only problem is - each pic is different, but then when I click on them they all pop up to be the same picture.

I've tried putting puts statements through the flow of code and it definitely recognises that it's looping through up until I get past where it is commented "Modal" that's where it starts to break. I can't work out why

```
<% @painting.each do |paintwork| %>
  <% if paintwork.profile_id.to_i == @profile.id.to_i %>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <% if paintwork.artwork.attached? %>
        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
        <button type="button" class="btn popart" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
          <%= image_tag paintwork.artwork, class: "d-block w-100 shadow p-3 mb-3 bg-white rounded" %>
        </button>

        <!-- Modal -->              
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Season<%= paintwork.season %>Episode<%= paintwork.episode %></h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <%= image_tag paintwork.artwork, class: "d-block w-100 shadow p-3 mb-3 bg-white rounded" %>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Current output is each pic is displayed differently as it should, but when I click any one of them it always comes up as the first picture and where it says "season" and "episode" they are always the same too. I'd be expecting the picture I click on to be the picture that comes up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is the modal is inside the loop, but the id it triggers will always grab the first one. Change the id on the modal to be specific to each instance, and make the id it is triggering on the button match.

```
 <% @painting.each do |paintwork| %>
      <% if paintwork.profile_id.to_i == @profile.id.to_i %>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <% if paintwork.artwork.attached? %>
                        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
          <button type="button" class="btn popart" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter-<%= paintwork.id %>">
            <%= image_tag paintwork.artwork, class: "d-block w-100 shadow p-3 mb-3 bg-white rounded" %>
          </button>

          <!-- Modal -->

          <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter-<%= paintwork.id %>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Season<%= paintwork.season %>Episode<%= paintwork.episode %></h5>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <%= image_tag paintwork.artwork, class: "d-block w-100 shadow p-3 mb-3 bg-white rounded" %>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Ah awesome fixed! Thank you 

Comment: Is it clear what went wrong there? This was something that use to get me all the time.  So, in the loop, those modals just needed their own unique id's, makes sense?